# Is a mysql-query logical or not?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sorry if the question is already asked somewhere, I can't find it.

I was asking myself a question : is a mysql-query *logical* or not ?

Let's imagine : if I want to get all the posts of a topic of a forum, with the users'informations, I do :

```
SELECT p.p_id, p.p_text, p.p_uid, p.p_date,
   u.u_nickname, u.u_email
FROM posts as p
  JOIN users as u ON p.p_uid = u.u_id
WHERE p.p_id = :pid
```

We can imagine some users posted different times. Does the query try to get the users' informations each time it encounters a `u_id` or just when it encounters a different `u_id` it didn't see before ?

In a different way, if the user with `u_id = 1` posts ten posts, will the query get his informations ten times or just once ?

I believe this question is already solved somewhere, or even in the doc. But as you can see, english is not my first language, so there are many things I have trouble to understand.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: one time  ... a query is performed one time ..

Comment: MySQL uses an index to locate all of the rows applicable to the query. It is a once-time scan of the tuples contained in the tables.

Comment: Thank you guys ! It makes sense, but we don't always see logic in this world :D

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking - a MySQL query is logical by definition.  When you inner join two tables together, every row matched is returned.  So... every post will display the matching user's information (ten times if there are ten matches).

Comment: Yes @RMathis I get that, my question is not about what it is displayed, but what (and how many times) it is search'd ! Will the query search the users informations ten times, or will it search those once and apply them every time needed ?

Comment: SQL is, by definition, set oriented.  Your query will return one set of rows.  So, yes, a MySQL query is logical.

Comment: If multiple posts can be made to the same p.pid then the users table will be searched for each p.p_uid - even if the p.p_uid's are the same.

Comment: @RMathis The other answers seems to say the opposite... But just to be sure : `p.p_id` is the index so it's "unique". `p.p_uid` on the other hand can be the same for a multiple posts, in this case the query does search the users informations each time it encounters the same `p.p_uid` ?

Comment: yes..  the child table is searched for each parent - if the join is able to use an index then it will be used for the search (each indexed value represents a row - an index search can be a faster mechanism to look at the table values)  "explain select..." will show the execution plan to see if the index is used.  There are many different ways to join - Dr E.F. Codd designed it that way (relational algebra) - everything is set oriented - don't get caught up in the details... figure out how it works

Comment: Thank you very much @RMathis ! I take note of all that. :)